# What exactly is dispersive power of a medium?

Tags: terminology, geometric-optics, dispersion

In my textbook, it is written that dispersive power of a medium is the measure of its ability to disperse light.

$ω=\frac{θ}{δ_{mean}}$

where $ω$ is the dispersive power, ${θ}$ is the angular dispersion (${θ}= δ_{V}-δ_{R}$, where $δ_{V}$ is the deviation of violet light and $δ_{R}$ is the deviation of red light), and $δ_{mean}$ is the mean deviation which we take as the deviation of yellow light, $δ_{Y}$. Now, I have a question. If we have to measure the ability of a material to disperse light why don't we just measure its angular dispersion $θ$ itself? I mean angular dispersion is the measure of how much the light has dispersed, right? Why do we have to divide angular dispersion by mean deviation? From where did this mean deviation come? Angular dispersion clearly gives as an idea of how much the light has dispersed. We could have used angular dispersion itself as a measure of dispersive power of a material. Why divide it by mean deviation? What exactly is the meaning of the formula of dispersive power? What is the intuition behind this formula? Please explain. I am really confused.

Comment: If it helps, the definition isn't based on fundamental physics as much as on it's being a simple expression that describes observable differences in how light propagates through certain materials, consistently across experiments.

Comment: TLDR, could you please tell me how this formula came? Please give me a 'feel' or intuition for the formula.